# Search Bar and Search Display Controller on the ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a view controller, on it I have two buttons, I want that when user pressed on the button - searchBar appears and he'll can write some text and on the Search Display he'll can see result of the searching. This issue driving me crazy,  before I used only tableViews for it, and in data source methods check

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        // searching result
    }
    else
    {
       //just tableView
    }
```

How can I understood searchDisplayController and tableView - are separeted vc's, and for searching I don't need to have a tableView. But I cant implement it, I tried to search this question in net, on this portal, but cant found what I need. If any tutorials or example code about this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to understand is that you have two `UITableView`s in your ViewController. One is your normal `UITableView`, the other one is the `searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`. When you are in search mode, the normal `UITableView` is deactivated and the other one is activated. As both have the same Datasource and Delegate (in your VC), you need to check in all Delegate- and Datasource-methods if the calling TableView is one or the other and return the right result. For example in `numberOfRowsInSection` you might need to return 100 as the count of your full array, but only 20 as the count of your filtered array.

like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (aTableView == self.tableView) {
        return [self.contentArray count];
    } else {
        return [self.searchResultArray count];
    }
}
```

same for the other methods.

Comment: Can you show me some examples or source where I can see how do this please?